# Subclassing UserDefaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

tldr; why do we always use `UserDefaults.standard` instead of subclassing UserDefaults to make something that more precisely fits our needs?

Has anyone out there subclassed UserDefaults before? Or is that considered bad practice?

Say, for example, that we make a ColorDefaults subclass of UserDefaults. When the app, the ColorDefaults object is instantiated, and that *object* loads all its own data. And the loaded data can then by sent to an appropriate object via delegation, or made universally available via a singleton.

My running theory is that UserDefaults is only meant to store relatively amounts of data, so having to use a singleton enforces that idea.

Bottom line: do we use `UserDefaults.standard` because:

1. subclassing is frowned upon
2. we're supposed to avoid saving too much data to UserDefaults in general
3. there's just not much value in subclassing anyway?
4. pretty much anything else.

Comment: “Say, for example, that we make a ColorDefaults subclass of UserDefaults. When the app, the ColorDefaults object is instantiated, and that object loads all its own data” All of that makes sense except this being a subclass of UserDefaults. A string that reads itself from a file is a kind of string, not a kind of file.

Comment: Sub-classing shouldn't be necessary; use a binding and a ready-made instance of the `unarchiveFromDataTransformerName` value transformer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ColorDefaults` should not be a subclass of `UserDefaults`. It should be a plain struct or class with computed properties that are backed by `UserDefaults`.

Here is an example using static properties but you could refactor this to use a singleton class instead.

```
struct ColorDefaults {
    static var someDefault: String {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "someKey") ?? "some initial value"
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "someKey")
        }
    }
}

let someVal = ColorDefaults.someDefault // read
ColorDefaults.someDefault = "hello" // write
```

This would also be useful if one of your defaults was more complicated and needed to be encoded/decoded for `UserDefaults`. The logic goes in here and not all over your app.

Note that such a class should only be used to store small bits of preferences, not full blown app data.

Answer (score 0):

User defaults are a system of storage on file. There is little sense in subclassing unless you want to change some of its logic. But you can create multiple suits like `UserDefaults(suiteName: String)`. What do you expect you would do with subclassing? You could simply just globally define `let myDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: String)` and use it anywhere. I guess you could use methods like

```
class MyDefaults: UserDefaults {

    func saveName(_ name: String) {
        setValue(name, forKey: "name_key")
    }

}
```

But then again it might make more sense to just create an extension

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func saveName(_ name: String) {
        setValue(name, forKey: "name_key")
    }
}
```

Or make it a bit more complex:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    struct User {
        static let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "User")
        static func saveName(_ name: String) {
            defaults.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        }
    }

    struct General {
        static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        static func saveLastOpened(date: Date) {
            defaults.setValue(date, forKey: "last_opened")
        }
    }

}
```

But all of these have one fatal flow: Now you are dependent on using user defaults within the app. At some point you may find the need to rather save these data in some other form like a local JSON file synced with iCloud. I guess `UserDefaults.User` could be modified to do so but would be very ugly. What we want is not `UserDefaults.User.saveName("My name")` but `User.saveName("My name")`. From the interface perspective we do not care where this user name is saved and if a new system is introduced to save these data we don't want the change in interface.

In other words, imagine you are using `UserDefaults.User.saveName` on 100 places in your application and now want to use another system for saving user name. You will now need to change your code on 100 places to use `AnotherSystem.User.saveName` while if you simply use `User.saveName` the interface is still valid.

So the bottom line is there is no sense in (extensively) modifying, extending or subclassing `UserDefaults` because it is better creating a system that wraps `UserDefaults` and may later be changed to any other system.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are looking for something like this

```
class ColorDefaults : NSObject
{
    /// Save Data
    class func saveDataInDefaultForKey(_ key: String, _ data: Any){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    /// Retrieve data
    class func retrieveDataFromDefaultsWithKey(_ key: String) -> Any {
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as Any
    }
}
```

Save and get data:

```
/// Save Data
ColorDefaults.saveDataInDefaultForKey("myArray", myArray)
ColorDefaults.saveDataInDefaultForKey("myString", myString)

/// Get Data
if let valueString = ColorDefaults.retrieveDataFromDefaultsWithKey("myString") as? String {
        print("Saved Value String: \(valueString)")
 }
 else {
        print("Error retrieving myString")
 }

 if let valueArray = ColorDefaults.retrieveDataFromDefaultsWithKey("myArray") as? [String] {
        print("Saved Value Array: \(valueArray)")
 }
 else{
        print("Error retrieving myArray")
 }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why does `colorDefaults` extend `NSObject`? Why does is violate standard naming conventions?